# Paperclip shows missing image instead of defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Showing all user's photos works , but showing particular photos of one user don't (shows missing image instead of those defind by id). Route for getting particular image is `/users/:user_id/photos/:id`. This is my **Photos** controller:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

    before_action :find_user, only: [:index, :new, :create, :update]
    before_action :find_photo, only: [:show, :destroy]

    def index
        @photos = @user.photos
    end

    def new
        @photo = @user.photos.build
    end

    def show
    end

    def create
        @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)

        if @photo.save

            if params[:images]
                params[:images].each { |image|
                    @user.photos.create(image: image)
                }
            end

            redirect_to :action => :index

        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
        @photo = @user.photos.find(params[:id])

        if @photo.update
            redirect_to user_photos
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @photo.destroy

        redirect_to user_photos
    end

    private

    def find_user
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end

    def find_photo
        @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def photo_params
        params.require(:photo).permit(:title, :image, :user_id)
    end
end
```

This is my **Users** controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @search = User.search(params[:q])

        if @search
            @users = @search.result.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:strana])
        else
            @users = User.all.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:strana]).order("created_at DESC")
        end
    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
            redirect_to @user
        else
            render 'new'
        end     
    end

    def show
        find_params
        @photos = @user.photos
    end

    def edit
        find_params
    end

    def update
        find_params

        if @user.update(user_params)
            redirect_to @user
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        find_params
        @user.destroy

        redirect_to users_path
    end
```

This is *photos/show* view:

```
<%= image_tag @photo.image.url(:thumb) %>
```

This is *photos/index* view:

```
<% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>

    <%= image_tag(photo.image) %>
    <%= photo.title %>

<% end %>
```

Routes are nested:

```
resources :users do
    resources :photos
end
```

Comment: if you are trying to show all photos of a particular user it should be in user show page not in photos/show.

Comment: Well, my structure of the app is little different: on users/show are user informations, and there's a button _Photos_ which sends to index of that user's photos. Whatever, that wouldn't change anything about this because I'll still have to call `/users/:user_id/photos/:id` to see particular photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved - first images were actually not uploaded (I forgot to add validation) so they had nil value in image link field.

Comment: Give your answer the green tick to remove it from the waiting questions queue.

Comment: I can't do it right now - I need to wait one more day to accept my own answer.